# What is the proper update syntax for Kinetica?

Tags: kinetica

I'm using Kinetica 7.0.20.3, I need to update field F1 from table A using field F2 from table B, table A and B both can join on the key column, I tried update statement below, but didn't work.

```
update Table1 A, Table2 B 
set A.F1 = B.F2 
where A.pk = B.pk
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
UPDATE A
SET    A.F1 = B.F2
FROM   Table1 A
JOIN   Table2 B
ON     A.pk = B.pk
;
```

or

```
UPDATE A
SET    A.F1 = B.F2
FROM   Table1 A, Table2 B
WHERE  A.pk = B.pk
;
```